# Plivo hangup_call is not ending call

Tags: php, plivo

**Introduction**

We are using Plivo PHP Server-side SDK (legacy version) to manage inbound calls. Recently I had to implement call blocking. Idea is simple - If inbound call in our system does not match certain rules, we hang up. For that `hangup_call` function from RestAPI is used.

**Piece of Code**

When our system receives request with Event: `StartApp` from Plivo, call controller calls `StartCall` class function `handle`. This function contains all logic for starting call(checking rules, saving call in data base, start recording, etc):

```
public function handle($data) {
    // Finding caller from DB by callerNumber ...
    // Finding campaign from DB by targetNumber ...
    // Checking if caller already called in certain time interval (isDuplicate) ...

    // Starting call - call MUST be saved in DB !
    $call = Call::start($data["CallUUID"], $campaign, $caller, $isDuplicate);
    $call->save();

    try {
        // Checking call rules, throwing exceptions and changing call status accordingly
        $call->guardCall();
    } catch (CountryNotAllowedException $e) {
        // Hanging up if caller country not allowed
        return $this->callsApi->hangUp($call);
    } 
    // If everything went good waiting(Plivo addWait) for our systems waiting call service to find call consumer and execute transfer...
}
```

Note: `hangUp` is function that contains `hangup_call` alongside with some logging.

**Testing**

At the moment, for call testing we use skype with purchased US numbers since we are located in Europe.

For testing purposes, every call in this test does not pass rules - is blocked.

When testing this code everything seemed to work, but there is one issue - skype(caller) keeps connecting although Plivo ended call. In result, after our system receives `Hangup` from Plivo a new call starts. And this is repeating in cycle until I manually end call in skype as caller.

Using `addSpeak` or `addWait` instead of `hangup_call` works - speak or wait is executed and after that call ends.

I also tried use `addHangup` with parameter reason: "rejected", but there was no difference.

**Question**

**Why after `hangup_call` is executed skype keeps connecting? (Call is not ended in caller side)**

Could it be skype's peculiarity?

Maybe it is because we use legacy version SDK? Is there a big difference between latest and legacy Server-side SDK?

Comment: I don't think that's the recommended way to use exceptions.  Aside from that, is there a distinction between hanging up and refusing a call? I'm wondering if Skype has some sort of auto redial because it isn't registering that the call was refused.

Comment: What happens on the Skype caller's end when the call is rejected? Does it appear to disconnect and reconnect, or just continue ringing?

Comment: @Anthony In both cases - hangup and  rejecting (hangup with reason "rejected") Skype keeps ringing.

Comment: Are you by change using the sequential dial feature?  Also are you passing the CallUUID to the hang_up function? $plivo->hangup_call(CallUUID);  The relevant code and response would help figure it out.